# Why is Javascript Changing My Date?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am getting a date value back from an ajax request which looks like the following:

```
"2013-08-08T00:00:00"
```

Well that's no good, so I parse just the date:

```
mydate = mydate.substring(0,10);
```

Which gives me:

```
"2013-08-08"
```

Great, now I'll just make it a real date:

```
mydate = new Date(mydate.substring(0,10))
```

And get:

```
Wed Aug 07 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Huh? Why did I lose one day?

Comment: Do you happen to know what time zones are? And you didn't loose a month. It was August and it remained August.

Comment: My local machine is on (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

Comment: Which would probably translate to GMT-0400 with daylight saving being non-applied.

Comment: So it's subtracting 4 hours? I don't understand why it would use GMT instead of ET.

Comment: You should consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to parse your strings and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an interesting situation here indeed, this is caused by when you create a Date object, unless you specify a timezone offset, it assumes that your date input is in UTC time, then converts it.  This is only because you entered your value with '-' instead of '/'

**EDIT**: Correction, I believe your date may be taken in as UTC time, then converted to the appropriate EDT time.  This would explain why setting the exactly values or using '/' returns a different result.  '/' probably denotes EDT time, while '-' denotes UTC time.

See:

```
var asString = "2013-08-08T00:00:00" var mydate =
asString.substring(0,10);

var cDate1 = new Date(mydate);

var cDate2 = new Date(mydate.replace('-', '/'));

var asSplit = mydate.split('-'); 
var cDate3 = new Date(asSplit);

alert(cDate1 + "\n" + cDate2 + "\n" + cDate3);
```

Which produces the following:

```
Wed Aug 07 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Thu Aug 08 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Thu Aug 08 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Where the cases are:

- Standard
- Replace '-' with '/'
- Separate into Year/Month/Day

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sEnE2/4/)

**EDIT**: Noted an error pointed out by loxxy

Comment: GMT is the same as UTC.

Comment: Oops. meant EDT not GMT

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making it `2013,08,08` instead
seems it doesn't like the hyphens

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Date object takes

`var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
new Date("2013-08-08".split("-"))
```

So In your case :

```
new Date(mydate.substring(0,10).split("-"))
```